# Special and Practical Mathematical Use of Cantor's Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Cantor's Theorem:**
>
> SSuppose that $A$ is a set and $f:A\to\mathcal{P}(A)$ is any function, then $f$ is not surjective

The proof is quite simple; we must conjure a $D \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ for which there is no $a \in A$ st $f(a) = D$.

1. As others before me have devised, put $D = \{ a \in A: a \not\in f(a) \}$.
2. Take $a \in D$. Then $a \not \in f(a)$. Then $f(a) \not= D$ (otherwise $a\in f(a) = D$ , but $a \not \in f(a)$)
3. Take $a \not\in D$. Then $a \in f(a)$. Then $f(a) \not = D$ since then $a \in f(a) = D$, but $a \not\in D$
4. There is no $a$ such that $f(a) = D$ so $f$ is not surjective. $\square$

**Q**: Are there any other interesting sets $D^\prime$ in the power set of $A$ for which there is no $a$ such that $f(a) = D^\prime$. What if we postulated that in fact $D$ is the only set that breaks the surjection, and postulated

> Suppose that $A$ is a set and $f$ is any function, such that $f:A\to(\mathcal{P}(A)-\{D\})$ where $D$ is defined as before. Then $f$ can be
> surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $D$ is defined with respect to a particular $f$ so this $f$ is either surjective onto the range $\mathcal P(A)-\{D\}$ or not.

And it won't be unless $A$ has zero or one elements.

The proof for a finite $A$ is simply counting. If $A$ has $n$ elements $\mathcal P(A)-\{D\}$ has $2^n-1$ elements which is too many to support a surjective function since its greater than $n$ (for $n\ge 2$).

For infinite $A$, $\mathcal P(A)$ will also be infinite. Take a countable sequence from $\mathcal P(A)-\{D\}$ (this requires some weak choice principle). Any surjection onto $\mathcal P(A)-\{D\}$ will yield a surjection onto $\mathcal{P}(A)$ by swapping $D$ with the first element of the sequence and then shifting all the others, like Hilbert's hotel.

Comment: Can you explain why $f:A\to (\mathcal{P}(A) - \{D\})$ is most certainly not surjective?

Comment: @theideasmith edited to answer that and remove references to things you've changed in your question